# Fixed Header on Mobile with oversized page body

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile

I have a webpage with a fixed header like usual:

```
.header{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

The main body of the page is a svg image that is 1200px wide. On mobile, this makes the header stretch to 1200px and require scrolling to view it all.

I want the header to behave as a fixed header should - be exactly the width of the screen, and remain fixed - regardless if the main body is scrolled vertically or horizontally, and optimally, even if it is zoomed.

EDIT: I tried using `100vw` instead of `100%` and it works a little better - the header doesn't expand wider than the screen. But the header still scrolls out of site when scrolling the body.

**Update:** From the comments, it looks like you all aren't getting the problem. Here is a codepen to demonstrate. If you view it on desktop, it works fine. But when I view it on my iphone 5 safari browser, the header is stretched to the width of the image.

http://codepen.io/life4ants/full/LWybQZ/

Comment: Of course it works just fine on a desktop browser. But mobile phones are different somehow. I checked your codepen on my phone, and it has just the problem I'm describing.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the phone is acting as a viewport on a wider page. Do you have a meta viewport command on the page?

Comment: probably, you have an element on your page that makes the body wide, most probably it is something absolute positioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
   maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

And wrapping the page with:

```
.bg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: This is what I really wanna find! Thanks